# How can you query for JIRA tickets resolved by automatic github transitions?

Tags: jira

The scenario here is that we have JIRA set up so that issues get resolved (status transitions to Resolved) automatically when a GitHub PR gets merged.

In the history tab, this shows up as:

`Automated transition triggered when <User Name> merged pull request #76 in GitHub - 2 days ago`

How can I make a query in JIRA to find all the issues resolved in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a comment being added to an issue with that text? Then it should be like:

```
comment ~ "Automated transition triggered when"
```

Comment: No comment, it does show up as a history item though.  I guess this might be the way to do it: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/833/issue-history-through-rest-api